# Auto-Populate Image After Media Upload

Tags: plugin-development, themes

I am trying to auto-populate an image on a theme page using the native Wordpress media uploader, but I want the image to populate before the option is saved.   With the code below, the url to the image is populating correctly into the `input` field automatically, but I cannot figure out how to get the image to display:

```
<td>
  <label for="upload_image">
      <input style="float:left; width:80%" id="upload_image" type="text" name="upload_image" value="<?php echo $options['upload_image']; ?>" />
      <input style="float:right" id="upload_image_button" type="button" value="Upload Image" />
  <br/>

  <img id="upload_image" name="upload_image" src="<?php if ($options['upload_image'] != "" ) { echo $options['upload_image']; } ?>" />
  </label>

</td>
```

ADDED CODE:

Here is the script for the #upload_image_button

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery('#upload_image_button').click(function() {
 formfield = jQuery('#upload_image').attr('name');
 tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
return false;
});

window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
 imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
 jQuery('#upload_image').val(imgurl);
 tb_remove();
}

});
```

Comment: This has to be solved with jQuery. Where is the rest of the code? The part that takes care of `#upload_image_button`

Comment: I'm going to assume the old thickbox, but since this is a theme I'm going to need it to accomodate both.  What code would accomplish this?

Comment: Okay, I posted the code.....take a look

Comment: Use a dollar sign in `jQuery(document).ready(function($){});`, so inside the function you can refer to `jQuery()` as `$()`.

Comment: brasofilo - the image uploader is for 3.5.....your code didn't work.  So do you have any leads on code for the new 3.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same call where the image URL is being sent to the editor, you fill up another div with an image source.

Like:

```
window.send_to_editor = function(html) 
{
    imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
    jQuery('#upload_image').val(imgurl);
    imgsrc = '<img id="upload_image" name="upload_image" src="'+imgurl+'">';
    jQuery('#image-holder').html(imgsrc);
    tb_remove();
}
```

*PS: this is for the Old Thickbox, not for the New 3.5 Uploader, which has very few examples nowadays.*

[update]
In the original theme page code, the image should be wrapped in:

```
<div id="image-holder"><img id="upload_image" name="upload_image" src="<?php if ($options['upload_image'] != "" ) { echo $options['upload_image']; } ?>" /></div>
```

Comment: @RobMyrick, did you debug this? ::: `console.log('the image source is = ' + imgsrc);` ::: Does `#an-empty-div` corresponds to an existent element? ::: AFAIK, the Javascript you posted is for the old uploader and this `window.send_to_editor` *should be doing its work*.

Comment: Sorry, brasofilo, I don't know anything about jQuery so I'm confused as to exactly what I should be doing.  We are almost there I'm sure!

Comment: Okay, I just finally understood what you meant by `Does #an-empty-div corresponds to an existent element?`, so I added an empty div with that id and the code worked.  Thanks man!  Btw, you answer quite a few of my questions - are you a theme developer?

Comment: Plugin developer ;) Nice that you figured it out, I've updated the answer, so any future visitor won't have the same doubt.